# Ошибка при авторизации доменного пользователя

Tags: linux, авторизация, kerberos, контроллер-домена

При попытке авторизоваться в приложении через вебморду под доменной учетной записью вылезает такая ошибка:
{"error":"GssApiException: GSSAPI operation failed with error - Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information (Feature not available)."}

Приложение развернуто на AstraLinux (виртуалка), машина заведена в домен, для авторизации использую Google Chrome (так же пробовал авторизоваться через Яндекс браузер и Brave как на виртуалках с windows 10 так и на локальной машине с windows 10 - результат один и тот же).

Насколько я понял это происходит потому что стоит авторизация через NTLM а должна быть через Kerberos.

P.S.Перепробовал много различных гайдов - ничего не помогло.